Can you load a WAVES VST plugin with Audio Toolbox?
I'm trying to load a VST3 plugin from WAVES using loadAudioPlugin() from MATLAB Audio Toolbox:
loadAudioPlugin('/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3/WaveShell1-VST3 14.17.vst3')

but I get the following error:
Unexpected unknown exception from MEX file..
Error in hostmexif.newplugininstance

Error in loadAudioPlugin

This seems to be due to Waves using WaveShell as a software gateway to the actual VST plugin -- see https://www.waves.com/support/how-to-use-waves-plugins-when-using-custom-vst-folder
Anyone has had any success loading a Waves VST3 plugin into MATLAB?

IIRC, at some point years ago, it was possible to load Waves plug-ins directly to a VST host software but, dunno if they allow it anymore or can't remember if it was a separately bought plug-in in question.
